# Cocos2d-X Show CCCsprite on Touch

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am using two `CCSprite` objects which are at the same position. One object is shown but other object will be hidden, I want to show the portion of hidden sprite where user touches.

I've tried CCMask but the desired effect is not achieved. Anyone know how to obtain this effect in Cocos2d-X.

Comment: you mean to say when u  having 2 sprites on same position : by default sprite 1 will b shown & sprite 2 will be invisible but when we click on sprite 1 then sprite 2 should be visible & sprite1 will be invisible , Like this ?

Comment: You can use a CCRenderTexture as a stencil to draw over the CCClippingNode.

Comment: @Nadarian thankyou so much... i worked by using CCClippingNode